# Leaflet map extending to next page when printing

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

I've been working on a web project that involves mapping, and I've run into an issue where a leaflet panel will show up on the next page.

[image: Issue displayed here]

When I resize the map, the extra bit on the next page moves with it, and the extra panel has the correct image for its placement relative to the main map. Is this an issue with Leaflet, or am I missing something about how to print it?

I'm using jquery 1.12.3 and leaflet 1.2.0, and it shows up on every browser I've checked with.